# zclip within a function

Tags: jquery, zclip

I never used zclip but after googling knew how to call zclip.

```
$("#copy").zclip({
    path: "js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy: function(){
        return $(this).prev().val();
    }
});
```

But I have many buttons, they are working as share buttons. Clicking any button a function gets executed. I have to copy a string within the function.

```
function copy(commentId){
    var share_path = window.location.protocol + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '#';
    share_path += <?='"'.$sharePath.'"';?> + commentId;
    //copy the string share_path
    alert(share_path);
}
```

How would you solve this? Please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this

```
prompt('Please copy this link to share', share_path);
```

Hope it'll also work for you.